# Operadores AND e OR

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria

Comecei a usar recentemente a Criteria API, pois preciso fazer consultas que seriam muito complexas com HQL.

Como eu uso os operadores `AND` e `OR` nas queries com Criteria API?

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow, Roger! Por favor visite a [Central de ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) para entender melhor como o site funciona, e faça o [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)! (Vale uma medalha...)

Comment: O que você procura pode está aqui: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html, na seção
Expression Methods in the CriteriaBuilder Interface

Answer (score 1):

Seria esse o exemplo de sintaxe que você procura?

```
CriteriaQuery<Pet> cq = cb.createQuery(Pet.class);
Root<Pet> pet = cq.from(Pet.class);
cq.where(cb.equal(pet.get(Pet_.name), "Fido")
    .and(cb.equal(pet.get(Pet_.color), "brown")));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery();
Root employee = criteriaQuery.from(Employee.class);
criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.and(
                    criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(employee.get("salary"), 100000),
                    criteriaBuilder.lessThan(employee.get("salary"), 200000)));
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<Employee> result = query.getResultList();
```

Essa query retorna empregados com salarios entre 100000 e 200000.
Basicamente os operadores AND e OR vem primeiro e dentro deles, separado por virgulas, vem as condições.

AND(condicao1,condicao2,condicao3...)

Tu também podes colocar um dentro do outro:

AND(OR(condicao1,condica2),condicao3)

Segue referencia:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria#Where